# Model multiple imputation with interaction terms

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, interaction, r-mice

According to the documentation of the `mice` package, if we want to impute data when we're interested in interaction terms we need to use passive imputation. Which is done the following way.

```
library(mice)
nhanes2.ext <- cbind(nhanes2, bmi.chl = NA)
ini <- mice(nhanes2.ext, max = 0, print = FALSE)

meth <- ini$meth
meth["bmi.chl"] <- "~I((bmi-25)*(chl-200))"

pred <- ini$pred
pred[c("bmi", "chl"), "bmi.chl"] <- 0

imp <- mice(nhanes2.ext, meth = meth, pred = pred, seed = 51600, print = FALSE)
```

It is said that

```
Imputations created in this way preserve the interaction of bmi with chl
```

Here, a new variable called `bmi.chl` is created in the original dataset. The `meth` step tells how this variable needs to be imputed from the existing ones. The `pred` step says we don't want to predict `bmi` and `chl` from `bmi.chl`.  But now, if we want to apply a model, how do we proceed? Is the product defined by `"~I((bmi-25)*(chl-200))"` is just a way to control for the imputed values of the main effects, i.e. `bmi` and `chl`?

If the model we want to fit is `glm(hyp~chl*bmi, family="binomial")`, what is the correct way to specify this model from the imputed data? `fit1` or `fit2`?

```
fit1 <- with(data=imp, glm(hyp~chl*bmi, family="binomial"))
summary(pool(fit1))
```

Or do we have to use somehow the imputed values of the new variable created, i.e. `bmi.chl`?

```
fit2 <- with(data=imp, glm(hyp~chl+bmi+bmi.chl, family="binomial"))
summary(pool(fit2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With passive imputation, it does not matter if you use the passively imputed variable, or if you re-calculate the product term in your call to `glm`.
The reason that `fit1` and `fit2` yield different results in your example is because are not *just* doing passive imputation for the product term.

Instead you are transforming the two variables befor multiplying (i.e., you calculate `bmi-25` and `chl-100`). As a result, the passively imputed variable `bmi.chl` does not represent the product term `bmi*chl` but rather `(bmi-25)*(chl-200)`.

If you just calculate the product term, then `fit1` and `fit2` yield the same results like they should:

```
library(mice)
nhanes2.ext <- cbind(nhanes2, bmi.chl = NA)
ini <- mice(nhanes2.ext, max = 0, print = FALSE)

meth <- ini$meth
meth["bmi.chl"] <- "~I(bmi*chl)"

pred <- ini$pred
pred[c("bmi", "chl"), "bmi.chl"] <- 0
pred[c("hyp"), "bmi.chl"] <- 1

imp <- mice(nhanes2.ext, meth = meth, pred = pred, seed = 51600, print = FALSE)

fit1 <- with(data=imp, glm(hyp~chl*bmi, family="binomial"))
summary(pool(fit1))
# > round(summary(pool(fit1)),2)
#                est    se     t    df Pr(>|t|)   lo 95 hi 95 nmis  fmi lambda
# (Intercept) -23.94 38.03 -0.63 10.23     0.54 -108.43 60.54   NA 0.41   0.30
# chl           0.10  0.18  0.58  9.71     0.58   -0.30  0.51   10 0.43   0.32
# bmi           0.70  1.41  0.49 10.25     0.63   -2.44  3.83    9 0.41   0.30
# chl:bmi       0.00  0.01 -0.47  9.67     0.65   -0.02  0.01   NA 0.43   0.33

fit2 <- with(data=imp, glm(hyp~chl+bmi+bmi.chl, family="binomial"))
summary(pool(fit2))
# > round(summary(pool(fit2)),2)
#                est    se     t    df Pr(>|t|)   lo 95 hi 95 nmis  fmi lambda
# (Intercept) -23.94 38.03 -0.63 10.23     0.54 -108.43 60.54   NA 0.41   0.30
# chl           0.10  0.18  0.58  9.71     0.58   -0.30  0.51   10 0.43   0.32
# bmi           0.70  1.41  0.49 10.25     0.63   -2.44  3.83    9 0.41   0.30
# bmi.chl       0.00  0.01 -0.47  9.67     0.65   -0.02  0.01   25 0.43   0.33
```

This is not surprising because the `~I(bmi*chl)` in `mice` and the `bmi*chl` in `glm` do the exact same thing. They merely calculate the product of the two variables.

**Remark:**

Note that I added a line saying that `bmi.chl` should be used as a predictor when imputing `hyp`. Without this step, passive imputation has no purpose because the imputation model would neglect the product term, thus being incongruent with the analysis model.